# guildMemberAdd event not working even with intents enabled. (discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to set up a welcome message function on my discord bot, but no matter what I do, the bot doesn't seem to be able to use guildMemberAdd. I'm aware of the new update, and as suggested I've turned on both options under `Private Giveaway Intents`. But it still does not work. Here is my code:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const emb = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('#FFBCC9')
          .setTitle("new member")
          .setDescription("welcome to the server!")
    member.guild.channels.get('780902470657376298').send(emb);
});
```

I have also found an answer online suggesting to use this:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { intents: new Discord.Intents(Discord.Intents.ALL) }});
```

But no matter how I write that, my bot just won't even come online unless I use `const client = new Discord.Client();` with nothing in the parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With v12 coming along, in order to get your full channels list you're only able to get the cached ones in your server. Hence why you should change this line:

```
member.guild.channels.get('780902470657376298').send(emb);
```

to:

```
member.guild.channels.cache.get('780902470657376298').send(emb);
```

Answer (score 1):

You passed in the intents params wrong. Here is the correct way to do it.

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ ws: { intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MEMBERS', 'GUILD_PRESENCES'] } });
```

If you use this the guildMemberAdd event will emit.

Make sure you have intents turned on in the developer portal. As Shown in this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDdxT.png.